# Matplotlib - How to draw table bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

Coming from a SQL backend, I have the below information in a dataframe.

How can I plot a table with bar charts?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the built-in [styling functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Bar-charts) of pandas dataframes. Below is an example taken from the pandas documentation.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

df.style.bar(subset=['A', 'B'], color='#d65f5f')
```

produces the following HTML output:

[image]